# Connect-PnPOnline always returns "...does not match one in the Microsoft account system"

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

When I try to connect to a SharePoint Online via Powershell (using the script below) I always receive the error...

```
Connect-PnPOnline : The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system.
```

This would make sense if MFA was enabled.  It is not.  I am also able to connect to other SharePoint Online sites fine.

Powershell Script

```
$URL = "https://mysite.sharepoint.com"
$login = "user@mysite.com"
$pwd = "secure-password"

$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $pwd -AsPlainText -Force;
$credentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $login, $pwd

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $url -Credentials $credentials
```

Comment: Seems the issue is happening in specific site, can you login into the site with same username/password in browser ?

Comment: @Jerry_MSFT yes.

Answer (score 0):

Likely due to Modern Auth.

Try:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://tenantName.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName -UseWebLogin
```

Comment: "UseWebLogin" will work but how do you can not store credentials with that flag.

Comment: You shouldn't store credentials. Use the Graph API with Client ID + Certificate, instead.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-application-id-and-authentication-key

You can then use Connect-PnPOnline -Url -ClientId <value> -Certificate (or -CertificatePath, etc.).

Comment: That is just for an example. Once it's working then I can use credential manager.  Regardless it doesn't work as intended.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by doesn't work as the CID/Secret|Certificate certainly does work. Cred Manager, if I recall, will not work since you need to content with Modern Auth + MFA.